# How to check a pattern in a string in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, if-statement

I want to check if a specific pattern was in a string to do some action

```
[filename pathname]=uigetfile
fullpath=[pathname filename]
```

In my program I will only browse for Pictures ,  all pictures are named with that pattern

*_cam1.jpg , *_cam1.jpg , *_cam2.jpg *_cam2.jpg , *_cam3.jpg

What I want to do to check if the image ends with cam1 then do some logic

```
if (filename.contain(cam1)
 then imread('1.jpg')
elseif (filename.contain(cam2)
 then imread ('2.jpg)
```

I know that there no method called 'contain' in matlab but this is an example to demonstrate what I want.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complex searches you can use regular expressions, but in this simple case a string comparison is enough.

```
% Let the user choose only files that end in .jpg
[filename pathname]=uigetfile('*.jpg');
% Use fullfile to join file parts! It is OS independent. 
fullpath=fullfile(pathname, filename);

if length(filename) > 8 && strcmp(filename(end-8:end),'_cam1.jpg')
    stuff = imread(fullpath);
    ...
elseif length(filename) > 8 && strcmp(filename(end-8:end),'_cam2.jpg')
    stuff = imread(fullpath);
    ...
end
```

It is not the most glamorous code, but it should get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

You can select a folder and then import only those pictures which match a pattern by using directly `dir()` and wildcard `*`:

```
dir('C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\*_cam*.jpg')
```