# How can I implement wildcard at ismember function of matlab?

Tags: matlab, string-matching

How can I do the implementation doing this in matlab;

```
ismember(file_names,['*.mp4'])
```

Comment: Are you getting `file_names` with `dir()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check a pattern in a string in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241603/how-to-check-a-pattern-in-a-string-in-matlab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do that with `regexp`, like this:

```
result = ~cellfun(@isempty,(regexp(file_names,'\.mp4$')));
```

For example,

```
file_names = {'aaa.mp4','bbb.mp3'};
```

gives

```
result =

     1     0
```

Comment: The dot (`.`) in `regexp` will be interpreted as any character, you should escape it: `\.`.

Comment: No problem. Also note that curiously `cellfun('isempty', ...)` is much faster than `cellfun(@isempty, ...)` (see details [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost/)).

Answer (score 3):

#### Using regular expressions (regexp)

This can be easily achieved with [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
tf = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(file_names, '.*\.mp4'));
```

If you want to force the pattern matching to the beginning or the end of the filename, you should add a caret (`^`) or a dollar sign (`$`) respectively, for instance:

```
%// Match pattern at the beginning of the filename
tf = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(file_names, '^.*\.mp4'));

%// Match pattern at the end of the filename
tf = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(file_names, '\.mp4$'));
```

#### Alternative method (strfind)

If your search pattern is simple enough, you can use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) instead:

```
tf = ~cellfun('isempty', strfind(file_names, '.mp4'));
```

Note that this method does not allow you to search for more complicated patterns, nor check conditions (trivially) such as the appearance of the pattern at the end of the string...

Comment: Note that there's also the `regexptranslate` function that converts wildcard-patterns to regular expressions.