# Separating an array based on whether it contains a phrase or not

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am really just a noob at Matlab, so please don't get upset if I use wrong syntax. I am currently writing a small program in which I put all .xlsx file names from a certain directory into an array. I now want to separate the files into two different arrays based on their name. This is what I tried:

```
files = dir('My_directory\*.xlsx')
file_number = 1;
file_amount = length(files);
while file_number <= file_amount;
    file_name = files(file_number).name;
    filescs = [];
    filescwf = [];
    if strcmp(file_name,'*cs.xlsx') == 1;
        filescs = [filescs,file_name];
    else
        filescwf = [filescwf,file_name];
    end
    file_number = file_number + 1
end
```

The idea here is that `strcmp(file_name,'*cs.xlsx')` checks if `file_name` contains 'cs' at the end. If it does, it is put into `filescs`, if it doesn't it is put into `filescwf`. However, this does not seem to work...

Any thoughts?

Comment: instead of `strcmp` you could use [`findstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findstr.html). i.e. `if ~isempty(finstr(file_name, 'cs.xlsx'))` but also dont put a `;` after the `if` line!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp(file_name,'*cs.xlsx')` checks whether `file_name` is identical to `*cs.xlsx`. If there is no file by that name (hint: few file systems allow '*' as part of a file name), it will always be false. (btw: there is no need for the '==1' comparison or the semicolon on the respective line)

You can use array indexing here to extract the relevant part of the filename you want to compare. `file_name(1:5)`, will give you the first 5 characters, `file_name(end-5:end)` will give you the last 6, for example.

Comment: thanks for answering. I came up with the following way of trying to solve my problem. I first made use of `[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(char(file_name))` to get just the name. Then I defined `endletters = name(end-1:end)`. I finally changed the equality check to `strcmp(endletters,'cs')`. However, the program still does not do what I want it to do... One problem apart from the sorting is that my arrays don't seem to grow... For instance, I see in the output that a lot of the names get send to the filescwf array, but when I check its content on the end, I only get one filename...

Comment: Even if you name vour variable `file_name`, Matlab treats it the same way like any other character sequence. Thus, the dot and what comes after it are characters like all others before it, i.e. to match `cs.xlsx` at the end, you need to check the final 7 characters.

Comment: @Matthias As for "... I only get one filename" - please check again. Make sure you check the full `filescwf` array, not just the beginning. Then read about Matlab's cell arrays. :-)

Comment: I've got it now :D The reason why my arrays remained empty was very stupid. The definition of the empty array was within the loop. The program now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` doesn't work with wildcards such as `*cs.xlsx`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241603/how-to-check-a-pattern-in-a-string-in-matlab) for an alternative approach.

Comment: BTW you could use a `for` loop instead of your `while` loop: `for file_number = 1:length(files)`.

Comment: thanks for answering. I am going to try to get around the wildcard by using the suggestion made by arne.b in the next answer. The while loop is for what is going to come next, but that is outside of this question.

Comment: If you check the question I linked in my answer, it's the same idea as arne b.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp` to check the final letters of each of your files, then `cellfun` to apply `regexp` to all your filenames.

Here, `getIndex` will have 1's for all the files ending with `cs.xlsx`. The `(?=$)` part make sure that `cs.xlsx` is at the end.

```
files = dir('*.xlsx')
filenames = {files.name}';   %get filenames

getIndex = cellfun(@isempty,regexp(filenames, 'cs.xlsx(?=$)'));
list1 = filenames(getIndex);
list2 = filenames(~getIndex);
```